# Application not registered error when using react-native-navigation with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I am seeing an error saying "Application is not registered" when trying to initialize react-native app using react-native-navigation's 'startSingleScreenApp' function.

library versions:

> react-native: 0.54.0, react-native-navigation: 1.1.407

I have a root reducer for navigation:

```
export default function createReducer(initialState, handlers) {
return function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
    if (handlers.hasOwnProperty(action.type)) {
        return handlers[action.type](state, action)
    } else {
        return state
    }
}}

export const navigate = createReducer(
Immutable({
    root: undefined
}), {
    [types.NAV__APP_ROOT_CHANGED](state, action) {
        if (state != null) {
            return state.merge({
                root: action.root
            });
        } else {
            return state;
        }
    }
});
```

Registering screens:

```
export function registerScreens (store, provider) {
Navigation.registerComponent('app.init', () => AppRoot, store, provider);
Navigation.registerComponent('app.login.registration', () => LoginRegistration, store, provider);}
```

App entry point: (index.js)

```
export default class App {
constructor() {
    store.subscribe(this.onStoreUpdate.bind(this));
    store.dispatch(navActions.appInitialized('login'))
}

onStoreUpdate() {
    const {root} = store.getState().navigate;
    if (this.currentRoot != root) {
      this.currentRoot = root;
      this.startApp(root);
    }
}

startApp(root) {
    switch (root) {
        case 'login':
            Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({
                screen: {
                    screen: 'app.init',
                    title: 'App'
               }
           });
           return;
        default:
           return;
    }
}}
const app = new App();
```

I can see the action being dispatched and handled by the store subscribe but the app doesn't load. I just see an error saying 'app' is not registered (root react-native folder is 'app')

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I deleted my node_modules and reinstalled, it helps but the app crashes again if new dependencies are added.

Comment: I tried doing the same with different version but still run into the same issue. What versions of react-native and react-native-navigation are you using ? At tthis time we are moving forward with react-navigation but would love to get back on react-native navigation. Thanks for the response

Comment: Hi, can you solve this issue?